# Migrating data from Plone to Liferay, or how could I retrieve information from Plone's Data.fs

Tags: python, liferay, plone, zope, zodb

I need to migrate data from a Plone-based portal to Liferay. Has anyone some idea on how to do it?

Anyway, I am trying to retrieve data from Data.fs and store it in a representation easier to work, such as JSON. To do it, I need to know which objects I should get from Plone's Data.fs. I already got the `Products.CMFPlone.Portal.PloneSite` instance from the Data.fs, but I cannot get anything from it. I would like to get the `PloneSite` instance and do something like this:

```
>>> import ZODB
>>> from ZODB import FileStorage, DB
>>> path = r"C:\Arquivos de programas\Plone\var\filestorage\Data.fs"
>>> storage = FileStorage.FileStorage(path)
>>> db = DB(storage)
>>> conn = db.open()
>>> root = conn.root()
>>> app = root['Application']
>>> plone_site = app.getChildNodes()[13] # 13 would be index of PloneSite object
>>> a = plone_site.get_articles()
>>> for article in a:
...    print "Title:", a.title
...    print "Content:", a.content
Title: <some title>
Conent: <some content>
Title: <some title>
Conent: <some content>
```

Of course, it did not need to be so straightforward. I just want some information about the structure of `PloneSite` and how to recover its data. Has anyone some idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Im doing small research which portal fits best my needs. Im really curious, why did you move from Plone to Liferay ?

Comment: @MarcinJancewicz I worked for a Liferay partner which was contracted to execute the migration. Actually, we did a lot of Plone-Liferay migrations. Plone (or, more precisely, Zope) was regarded as hard to develop and maintain. Also, ZODB was very prone to database corruption. I did not work with Plone directly but this was our customers told us. OTOH, I worked a lot with Liferay and it is an excellent tool. You are well advised to know JSP, servlets, Struts, Spring etc. and the official Liferay course will save you a lot of time and, once you know it all, you will be very productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've got ahold of the Plone site object, you can do a catalog query to find all content items in the site:

```
 >>> brains = site.portal_catalog.unrestrictedSearchResults()
```

This returns a list of "catalog brains", each of which contains some metadata about the item.  You can get the full item from the brain:

```
 >>> for b in brains:
 ...     obj = b.getObject()
```

Assuming your Plone site is using Archetypes-based content, you can then iterate through the fields of the item's schema and use each field's accessor to retrieve its value:

```
 >>> for field in obj.Schema().fields():
 ...     field_id = field.__name__
 ...     field_value = field.getAccessor(obj)()
```

Since the ZODB is an object database that stores pickled Python objects, you will need to have the correct version of Archetypes present in your Python environment, as well as the package that defines the class of the objects you're trying to retrieve.